# AndroidManifest.xml The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed

Tags: android

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.darklabs.silentmessanger">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SilentMessanger">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.

> Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig' property 'buildConfigPackageName'.
> Failed to query the value of property 'packageName'.
> > org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/d0k/AndroidStudioProjects/SilentMessanger/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 26; columnNumber: 10; The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited post to properly display whole manifest xml (xml needs to be fenced).

Now the problem clearly shows the misplaced line at bottom - remove it (or better, move it to first line).

See manifest structure here: https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filestruct